# How to draw a border line around a group of shapes automatically? [Visio]

Tags: microsoft-visio

I want to draw a borderline automatically around shapes like below.

[image]

Any suggestion?

Comment: Perhaps duplicate them , join them , make it grow a little, format it transparent with a borderEach of those steps is possible in macros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long try and error, I counted shapes on the page before and after Offset function then selected last added shape indices in the VBA environment, then `Union` them.

```
Public Sub makeborder()

Dim intCounter As Integer
Dim intShapeCount As Integer
Dim intShapeCount2 As Integer
Dim vsoShapes As Visio.Shapes
Dim vsoShapes2 As Visio.Shapes
Dim vsoSelection As Visio.Selection

Set vsoShapes = ActivePage.Shapes

intShapeCount = vsoShapes.Count

Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.Offset 0.045
Set vsoShapes2 = ActivePage.Shapes
intShapeCount2 = vsoShapes2.Count
ActiveWindow.DeselectAll
Set vsoSelection = ActiveWindow.Selection
For intCounter = intShapeCount + 1 To intShapeCount2
vsoSelection.Select vsoShapes(intCounter), visSelect
Next intCounter

vsoSelection.Union

End Sub
```